# AS3 iOS Baskerville font behaviour

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, fonts, air

I've found that not all fonts act equally in iOS using Adobe Air.

For example to get a bold and italic `Georgia` you have to use the `TextFormat` class this way and it works:

```
textFormat.font = "Georgia";
textFormat.bold = true;
textFormat.italic = true;
```

But now I want to use a bold and italic `Baskerville` and no matter what I do it always renders without bold or italic on the iOS device. It works fine on desktop. I've confirmed via multiple websites, and a font app in my ipad that the font indeed exists on the device.

I've also tried using the official iOS font name such as `Baskerville-BoldItalic` but it doesn't work either.

Any ideas?